# How to select iOS App build for macOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

When developing you can use Mac (Designed for iPad) which is running on iOS. When archiving I'm using "Any iOS device (arm64)". In the targets section in Xcode I have selected the iOS SDK for Mac (Designed for iPad).

In the iOS-App tab it lets me select a build I have uploaded. In the macOS tab it tells me I have to upload a build. So why can I not select an iOS build when submitting to the app store?

For some reason it's impossible to find any information on this. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: iOS apps are available to M1 macs as long as you don't opt-out. You do not need to upload a specific macOS build.  The ios build is used. The macOS section of App Store Connect is where you can upload a macos native version of your app for the Mac App Store.

Comment: If it's handled automatically - is there a way to separately adjust the description & screenshots for the Mac App Store?

Comment: Only if you release a native macOS app.